# Android: MobileFirst sending data from Native to cross page

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, json

My Task is as follows: using IBM MobileFirst create a Hybrid app and implement a JS calculator. show date retrieved from native java APIs to the web page.

My attempts:

1. I followed Documentations [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_sending_actions_native_to_js.html) and implemented the whole Native code onCreate method
2. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698289/how-to-achieve-interaction-between-native-and-hybrid-applications-in-worklight/26689642#26689642) answer"the first one" illustrating that i should use it on onInitWebFrameworkComplete,

   - Solution provided didn't work
   - I am working with MobileFirst version 7
   - full sample code is [provided](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yqlyw8dqlslz9c/NTGCalculator.rar?dl=0)

Suggestion: should i create the whole action bar in native code then merge it in the cross ui, is that available? I only need to send a petite string of date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear on your attempts, so here is a quick demonstration how to click a button in HTML and trigger the Send Action API to get the current Date in Java and return it to JavaScript, and then display it.

**index.html**

```
<button onclick="getDateFromJava();">show current date from Java</button>
```

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.App.addActionReceiver ("returneDdateFromJava", returnedDateFromJava);
}

function getDateFromJava() {
    WL.App.sendActionToNative("retrieveDate");
}

function returnedDateFromJava(received){
    if (received.action === "returnedDateFromJava"){ 
        alert (JSON.stringify(received));
    }
}
```

**main Java class file**

1. Find `onInitWebFrameworkComplete`
2. Add an `ActionReceiver` after the `else`:

   ```
   import com.worklight.androidgap.api.WLActionReceiver;
   ...
   ...

   public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
       if (result.getStatusCode() == WLInitWebFrameworkResult.SUCCESS) {
           super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
       } else {
           handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(result);
       }

       ActionReceiver ActionReceiver = new ActionReceiver();
       WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(ActionReceiver);
   }
   ```

**ActionReceiver class**

```
package com.getDateApp;

import java.util.Date;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL;
import com.worklight.androidgap.api.WLActionReceiver;

public class ActionReceiver implements WLActionReceiver{
    public void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject data){
        if (action.equals("retrieveDate")){
            Date date = new Date();

            JSONObject returnedDate = new JSONObject();
            try {
                returnedDate.put("dateFromJava", date);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("returnedDateFromJava", returnedDate);
        }
    }
}
```