# How To launch MobileFirst application on Physical device with native Activity implemented

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibm-mobilefirst, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a mobilefirst hybrid app project and I have implemented Activity subclass in its native project for bluetooth and google maps. Now if I run on a physical device, only the native activity launches and no html page is displayed. On the other hand if i try to run it on the emulator, the html pages are displayed but cant test the native side. (native activity searches for bluetooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the SendAction API to invoke native classes from the web code. See the following tutorial and documentation topic:

- Tutorial (and sample app): https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-ui-elements-hybrid-applications/
- Documentation: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html
- Example: [Android: MobileFirst sending data from Native to cross page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331579/android-mobilefirst-sending-data-from-native-to-cross-page)

Using the API you can make a call in wlCommonInit to execute your code in the native class and use that native functionality in your hybrid app.

Alternatively you can also implement a custom Cordova plug-in: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

Comment: OK so the part i was missing is that I needed to implement WLInitWebFrameworkListener class and implement its onInitWebFrameworkComplete function to load mainhtmlfile, so now i can see my html side on the app. Now what I want to do is initialize this framework on a listview item click event, but it doesnot let me since the context has changed

Comment: I had to add MyActivity.this instead of this to change the context!! Problem solved